# ConTeXt deletes file

Tags: context

Assuming I have `blatt1.tex`, I compile two version of it:

```
context blatt1.tex
context --mode=solution --result=loesung1.pdf blatt1.tex
```

I expect this to yield `blatt1.pdf` and `loesung1.pdf`. However, only `loesung1.pdf` exists afterwards. I assume `context` for some reason overwrites the default output name and then moves the file? Can I fix this behavior without renaming the source file to `temp.tex` or something?

It makes me feel very uneasy when a tool is deleting files it is not supposed to touch.

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt does not delete any output files.

What you observe is the defined behaviour. If you look in the [manual of the `context` script](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/context/scripts/mkiv/context.html) you will find

```
--result    name    rename the resulting output to the given name
```

So what actually happens is that `context --result=B A.tex` compiles `A.tex` to `A.pdf` and then moves `A.pdf` to `B.pdf`.